# How to pass variables to my SSM Run Command Document from my Lambda function and store it in a file in an ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-ssm

Based on a SNS notification with message containing 2 values t and c is triggered by a lightsail instance, this notification get into SQS and then message is read by the lambda, the lambda in turn takes the values t and c and uses ssm to run a command to replace the t and c value in a running ec2 instance, I'm able to get the t and c values printed on the lambda function, but how do i push it to the file in ec2 instance using SSM ?

lambda function:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
    describeInstance = client.describe_instances()
    
    InstanceId=[]
    for i in describeInstance['Reservations']:
        for instance in i['Instances']:
            if instance["State"]["Name"] == "running":
                InstanceId.append(instance['InstanceId'])
    
    for record in event['Records']:
       payload=record["body"]
       content = json.loads(payload)
       print(content["c"])
       print(content["t"])
       t = content["t"]
       c = content["c"]
       
    for instanceid in InstanceId:
        response = ssm.send_command(
                    InstanceIds=[instanceid],
                    DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
                    Parameters={
                        'commands': ["echo {T = {{$t}}} > /home/centos/testi.sh"]
                    } 
                )
                
        command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
        time.sleep(3)
            # fetching command output
        output = ssm.get_command_invocation(
                  CommandId=command_id,
                  InstanceId=instanceid
            )
        
        print(output)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

I need to pass values t and c to a file in the running instance, replacing the existing values, is that feasible ? or is there any workaround ?

Thanks You !

Comment: How big are these files? If these are small files you can base64 encode them and pass as strings. If bigger it would be better to pass them through S3.

Comment: @Marcin the file isn't big, just a script. So there no way i can pass from my lambda function to the ssm run command is it ?